# NoClassDefFoundError in wordcount program

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm running hadoop wordcount program. But it is giving me error like "NoClassDefFoundError"

command for running :

```
 hadoop -jar /home/user/Pradeep/sample.jar hdp_java.WordCount /user/hduser/ana.txt /user/hduser/prout
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: WordCount. Program will exit.
```

i've created the program in eclipse and then exported as jar file

Eclipse code :

```
package hdp_java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
 }

  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

}
```

Can anyone tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: Open your Jar with something like 7zip and check if your wordCount.class is where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the hadoop job which jar to use like so:

```
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

Also be sure to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

Use the following to add all the jar dependencies from (for example) current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.

Comment: Hi Quetzalcoatl,
I've added setJarByClass but still it is giving me error. but this time it is different one.
And all the dependent jars have been added in eclipse


Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/home/user/hpcc/lz_data/Pradeep/sample.jar

Comment: How are you making your jar?

Comment: I'm using the export->jar file option in the eclipse(indigo)

Comment: Thank You, it worked.
i was using below command 
hadoop -jar /home/user/Pradeep/sample.jar hdp_java.WordCount /user/hduser/ana.txt /user/hduser/prout 
instead of hadoop jar(wihtout hypen, "-")

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your code :

```
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

If it still doesn't work export this job as a jar and add it to itself as an external jar and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Tariq, 
After adding above line it is giving me different error.



Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/home/user/hpcc/lz_data/Pradeep/sample.jar